# adding new users VS existing users

Tags: usability, forms, registration

let's say that i have a form to enter members subscriptions in a fitness center club.

the "Add member" form contain the member personal data (first name, last name,phone, ... etc)
and the club plans and activities that he/she will subscribe.

now, what the best way to enter the member personal data , and in the same time search for an existing member that have the same first/last name,

in case that this member has already subscribed in this club before, and to prevent duplicate members data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reference the names and look for existing entries after you unfocus the last name field, but the problem is if you have users with the same name. Working for a company running national registration-oriented promotion campaigns, this happens more often than I had ever realized. We cross referenced name and email address as well, but since your scale is more local than ours I would say you could compare name entries to address entries, notifying the user entering that the name already exists, would they like to view the entry?, and after viewing ask to use the details from that entry (if the same person) or create a new member.

I'd definitely recommend running a check after entering the compared fields so you are not entering all their account details, only to submit the information and suddenly all that work was for nothing.

Comment: i am thinking to add a little datagrid near the inputs maybe in a flotaing semi transparent window to show existing members with their minimum personal data, and refresh it each keypress based on the inputs                   ,btw i am using WPF so this kind of effects is easy to do

Comment: If you are doing it, wouldn't you at least want to wait to get a baseline? So instead of doing it right away when I type my first letter, possibly start checking after the third or fourth character entry. Anything that is going to be moving and updating automatically will have motion and draw the user's attention so it is split from the action of submitting an entry. I'd say leverage this and make it clean and simple as possible. :)

Comment: good point ............   :)

Comment: finally,i think that i will do a double check, first showing existing members based on input fields , and another check after submiting the form, with comparing with first/last name and birth day

Comment: That sounds good!